# Oracle Golden gate replicat process abended

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle-golden-gate

2017-01-02 14:53:21  WARNING OGG-00869  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for Oracle, reptar.prm:  No unique key is defined for table 'BANKUSERSLOGIN'. All viable columns will be used to represent the key, but may not guarantee uniqueness.  KEYCOLS may be used to define the key.

2017-01-02 14:53:51  ERROR   OGG-00665  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for Oracle, reptar.prm:  OCI Error getting OCI_ATTR_NAME for UDT SYS.XMLTYPE (status = 24328-ORA-24328: illegal attribute value), SQL.

2017-01-02 14:53:51  ERROR   OGG-01668  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for Oracle, reptar.prm:  PROCESS ABENDING.

Comment: Besides sharing some error messages, do you have a question?

Comment: Good to hear that it abended. Awesome. So is it causing any problem to you. If yes, then mention it in your question

Answer (score 0):

Check if that is a new table created with XMLYPE column data type.

select distinct data_type from dba_tab_columns ;

select object_name,object_type, created from dba_objects where object_name in (select table_name from dba_tab_columns where data_type= 'XMLTYPE');

Add a new line in your EXTRACT parameter excluding this table from replication:

TABLEEXCLUDE SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME;